# Function taking sequential args and own previous value

Tags: clojure

I'm doing some work with [hidden markov models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_Model). More specifically, the forward and backward algorithms for filtering and smoothing. I've settled on a representation and have a working forward fn that takes the previous probability distribution for the hidden variable and the model and returns the new probability distribution. Now I want a filtering function that takes a sequence of sensor states and a model and returns a sequence consisting of

1. The initial state (contained within the model)
2. The result of using forward on the previous state in the return sequence, the next sensor state and the model.
3. Repeat 2 until no more sensor states remain.

I've managed to get this working by recursion, but since it's not a tail-position recursion it breaks recur and seems non-idiomatic and generally a bad solution. I've tried to formulate it to work with for, reductions and iterate but I can't seem to make any of them fit. Any way to improve it?

```
(defn filtering
  "Perform filtering to decide the likely state based on evidence.
  Returns a sequence of state probabilities given a sequence of evidence."
  [evidence {:keys [transition sense initial state-map] :as model}]
  (if (empty? evidence)
    (vector initial)
    (let [reading (first evidence)
          history (filtering (drop 1 evidence) model)
          previous-state (vector (peek history)) 
          fwd (forward previous-state reading model) ]
      (conj history fwd)
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion first goes down to the end of `evidence` and produces  `(:initial model)`. This is the initial value of the reductions.

Then each returning level of the recursion applies `#(forward %1 %2 model)` to the result of the application from the lower recursion level (as `%1`, taken by `peek`) and the next element of evidence (as `%2`). This code applies iteratively a two-argument function to consecutive elements of a sequence (taken in the reverse order) - clearly a case for `reduce`.

But those results are accumulated in the `history` vector which is returned to the upper levels of recursion. `reduce` with accumulated results is `reductions`. So I believe the structure of the code is roughly this:

```
(reductions #(forward %1 %2 model) (:initial model) (reverse evidence))
```

Comment: Swapped %1 for (vector %1) and it worked! Thanks a lot. Quick question though: That #()macro, is that equivalent to an anonymous (fn [a b])? Still finding my way around Clojure and I haven't seen it before.

Comment: @user1571406 Yes, it is a reader macro for anonymous function literal: http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters